# Installing pylucene using pip

Tags: java, python, lucene, pylucene

I'm reading about the install process for `pylucene` at https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html

Why is `pylucene` , unlike other Python libraries not available to install using pip?

My use case is to search a python dictionary using a DSL, in this case, I'm planning to try `pylucene`.

Comment: i'd say it's related more tp logistic matter on Lucene's side rather than pip's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that module is removed so you can't use it anymore

Comment: removed from where? pip?